# Is it possible to set RotateCertificates to false in KubeletConfiguration

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set RotateCertificates to false in the KubeletConfiguration of my kubadm.conf

This documentation suggests that it is possible: https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubelet/config/v1beta1#KubeletConfiguration
But when I run `kubadm init` the /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml contain `rotateCertificates: true`

All I have found when searching for the source of the problem is the following code that seems to suggest that the value is hardcoded to true: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ff809a5d953ba778270ce8790b21d394821e1e28/cmd/kubeadm/app/componentconfigs/kubelet.go#L173

Is it possible to set RotateCertificates to false in kubernetes 1.18 or is it hardcoded?
If it is possible to set it how does one do?

Comment: did you pass the KubeletConfiguration file in kubeadm init? if you ran kubeadm init before did you perform kubeadm reset before doing kubeadm init again?

Comment: Yes, I did both.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand and checked in this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/82103), it's hardcoded as true.

As @neolit123 mentioned in comments

> yes, enforcing a value of true, for a kubelet boolean field for which we cannot determine if the user has set it explicitly to false or if the language defaulted a structure field to false.
>
> this has to be fixed for kubelet v1beta2.

---

Additionally a  [commit note](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/82103/commits/c9b11980ffe2f0841cbd4d89431d1ae48424bbba)

> A recent commit added warnings for KubeletConfiguration and
> KubeProxyConfiguration fields that kubeadm cares about and
> does not recommend the user modifying them. Kubelet's
> "rotateCertificates" cannot be handled using this function
> as there is not way to figure out if the user has set it explicitly to
> "false". Hardcode the value to "true" and add a comment about that.